# AEM/CQ5 6.2 UTF-8 Character encoding

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, aem, iso-8859-1

I am not able to get special characters or the characters from a different language like French.
Already changed the Request Parameter from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8.
Made the changes in the Main Servlet as well.

For example : "İş hayatında ne çok engelle karşılaşıldığını, her rakamın değerini, zamanın en büyük rakip olduğunu, güvenliği elden bırakmamayı ve iyi bir iş ortağının önemini, bilen bilir. Sprinter’i ve yeni Vito’suyla, Mercedes-Benz hafif ticari araçlar kazanmak için doğdular.

Tıpkı sizin gibi."

While trying to generate a json output for this, it doesn't appear.

Please suggest a way.
Thanks.

Comment: Where are you trying to generate the JSON output from? Is this a custom servlet?

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure how your implementation is, below is an example that might help you for calling a service with UTF-8 data (taken your example data)

> Sample JSP that calls the Service reference with method parameter as
>   below

```
<%--
  Osgi HelloService Calling component.
--%><%
%>
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%><%
%><%@page session="false" %>
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject,java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="com.mycompany.mytestservice.HelloService" %>  
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!-- getting my service reference -->
<%
com.mycompany.mytestservice.HelloService hs = sling.getService(com.mycompany.mytestservice.HelloService.class);
%>

<!-- got the string back as jobject -->
<%
JSONObject jobject = hs.getJsonObj("İş hayatında ne çok engelle karşılaşıldığını, her rakamın değerini, zamanın en büyük rakip olduğunu, güvenliği elden bırakmamayı ve iyi bir iş ortağının önemini, bilen bilir. Sprinter’i ve yeni Vito’suyla, Mercedes-Benz hafif ticari araçlar kazanmak için doğdular. Tıpkı sizin gibi."); %>

<br/>
<b>UTF string converted to JSON Object ::</b><br/>
<!-- display into page -->
<%
out.println(jobject);
%>
```

> HelloService Interface

```
package com.mycompany.mytestservice;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

/**
 * A simple json service interface
 */
public interface HelloService {

    /**
     * @return the JSON Object of requested data
     */
    public JSONObject getJsonObj(String jsonobjp);

}
```

> HelloServiceImpl class

```
package com.mycompany.mytestservice.impl;

import javax.jcr.Repository;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.mycompany.mytestservice.HelloService;

/**
 * One implementation of the {@link HelloService}.
 */
@Service
@Component(metatype = false)
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService {

 protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public JSONObject getJsonObj(String jsonobjp){
    JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
    try { 
        jsonobj.put("testint", 30);
        jsonobj.put("myjspstring", jsonobjp); // adding to json object
        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        list.add("message 1");
        list.add("message 2");
        jsonobj.put("messages", list);
       log.info("*** JSON Object ***" + jsonobj);

    } 
 catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return jsonobj; // return json object
    }

}
```

which finally when the jsp called resulting the following output of the JSON object
[image: json output]

Note: make sure you handle the `\u2019` unicode character which is not as expected output because of the JSON implementation. have more details from [here](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/issues/225)

Another similar kind of example you can find [how-to-set-utf-8-response-on-dopost-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015668/how-to-set-utf-8-response-on-dopost-call)