# How to Set UTF-8 response on doPost() call?

Tags: java, jsp, osgi, aem, sling

I Am trying to have a JSON response back to the page with UTF-8 data, as it is what i have posted from the Form to my osgi servlet. The Servlet code is as shown below:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
    import org.json.simple.JSONObject;    

@SlingServlet(paths="/bin/JsonOsgiCall", methods = "POST", metatype=true)
public class JsonOsgiCall extends org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 2598426539166788515L;
     protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

     @Override
     protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServerException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();

    try { 

        jsonobj.put("testint", 30);
        jsonobj.put("myjspstring", request.getParameter("userinmsg"));
        jsonobj.put("myjspstati","`İş hayatında ne çok engelle karşılaşıldığını,`");
        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        list.add("message 1");
        list.add("message 2");
        jsonobj.put("messages", list);
       log.info("*** JSON Object with ***" + jsonobj.toJSONString());
       //out.println(jsonobj.toJSONString());
       out.println(jsonobj);  
    } 
 catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

And my JSP Form code shown as below:

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%><%
    %><%@page session="false" %>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject,java.io.PrintWriter,java.util.*"%>
    <%
    %>CALL OSGI SERVICE FOR JSON RESPONSE
    <cq:includeClientLib js="granite.csrf.standalone"/>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Editer les sous-titres</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="submitForm" method="POST" action="/bin/JsonOsgiCall">
        <textarea name="userinmsg" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="userinmsg" rows="4" cols="30" style="width: 450px; margin-left: 25px;">
        </textarea>
        <br/>

        <p style="margin-left: 420px;"><input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Call JSON Service" /></p>

      </form>
    </body>
```

But when I submit the Form and see the output that has resulted back to the page is like with ANSI format. Where the the JSON data that I have added in the:

`jsonobj.put("myjspstati","İş hayatında ne çok engelle karşılaşıldığını,");`

In between code snippet is coming fine back to page. But where as the form submitted same code is breaking when it received into servlet with:

`request.getParameter(userinmsg)`

How can I get the UTF enabled data that can be properly sent to Servlet and can do the JSON object with same.

[image: formsubmit]
[image: ServletResponse]

**Debugging in my browser Developer tools**
Request Headers
[image: Request Headers]

Response
[image: Response Headers]

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. Any server config you have tried? Is AEM running from jetty/jre or are you hosting via apache? Have you also checked your filter chain to see if something is changing the encoding? You can also try <form accept-encoding='UTF-8'> but doubt that will help here.

Comment: I have added  Felix console `Apache Sling Request Parameter Handling` `Default Parameter Encoding` to `_charset_=UTF-8`, and nothing else got changed. and the AEM is running in standalone local individual server not hosted via apache.

Comment: If you inspect the headers in your browsers dev tools, do you see correct encoding for respective req/response?

Comment: @i.net updated my question with screenshots of developer tools.

Comment: Can you try <form accept-encoding='UTF-8'> in your code?

Comment: @krish just add the `Default Parameter Encoding` value as `UTF-8` not as `_charset_=UTF-8` which should help.

Comment: @i.net `<form accept-encoding='UTF-8'>` didn't work. i have modified my form as `<form id="submitForm" method="POST" action="/bin/JsonOsgiCall" accept-encoding='UTF-8'>` which didn't worked.

Comment: @VAr thank you setting `Default Parameter Encoding` value as `UTF-8` is able to handle it. but strange observation is i have to restart the AEM to make it into work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see your charset is being broken(*as the ServerSide json data with utf-8 is resulted correct and you have a doubt in your request.getParameter()*) when it is getting transferred after form submission.

Try adding `<input type="hidden" name="_charset_" value="UTF-8"/>` where browser will fill-in the submitted character encoding as the field's value.

**Modified your form alone along with hidden input for charset utf-8**

```
<form id="submitForm" method="POST" action="/bin/JsonOsgiCall">
            <textarea name="userinmsg" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="userinmsg" rows="4" cols="30" style="width: 450px; margin-left: 25px;">
            </textarea>
            <br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="_charset_" value="UTF-8"/>
            <p style="margin-left: 420px;"><input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Call JSON Service" /></p>

          </form>
```

> **Another way of handling it at AEM level Felix Config**

Set your charset to UTF-8 in `Apache Sling Request Parameter Handling`  `Default Parameter Encoding` as shown below screenshot.
[image: Felix Charset]

~Hope it works

Comment: I thought about suggesting this but the OP has apparently set the relevant sling property which supersedes this requirement as per https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/request-parameters.html so I think this is a different issue. I am thinking of sling Filters now.

Comment: @i.net your are correct, i have missed out @Krish comment on `Apache Sling Request Parameter Handling`  `Default Parameter Encoding` to `_charset_=UTF-8` which is another way of forcing all the forms from AEM level to use UTF-8. Updated my answer along with this approach.

Comment: @VAr it worked as you suggested modified `Default Parameter Encoding` it to `UTF-8` then it started working. but observed the below behaviour.
1. Very first time changing the value to `_charset_=UTF-8` didn't worked.
2. Changing the value to `UTF-8` started working and able to see proper output.
3. and Changing back to `_charset_=UTF-8` also still works and resulted in proper output.
..** Strange but not sure how it behaves ** ..